# Problem adding my firebase project to my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So Im making an ecommerce react app, and decided to integrate firebase database to my project. I already created my first project on firebase and loaded all my products there with a random ID.
I imported firebase into my project. Problem is that the general product container seems to be working good but when i do the detail container (which is my one product page view), everything breaks. I will leave the code to each sections in which i implemented firebase database.

This is my cardliscontainer which seems to be working fine

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import productos from "../../utils/productsMock";
import CardList from "../CardList/CardList";
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import "./CardListContainer.css";

//Firestore
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from '../../utils/firebaseConfig';

const CardListContainer = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);
//
    const { idCategory } = useParams();


    
    const getProductoss = async () => {
        const productSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "products"));
        const productList = productSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            let product = doc.data()
            product.id = doc.id
            return product
        })
        return productList
    }
    

    const getProducts = () => {
        setSpinner(true);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(productos);
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
    

    useEffect(() => {
        getProductoss()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("productos", response)
                setSpinner(false);
                setProducts(
                    idCategory
                        ? response.filter(
                            (item) => item.category === idCategory
                        )
                        : response
                );
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Fallo.");
            });
    }, [idCategory]);


    return (
        <>
            {
                spinner

                ?

                <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    <LinearProgress />
                </Box>
                
                :

                <div className="general-container">
                    <CardList products={products} />
                </div>

            }
        </>
    )
};

export default CardListContainer;
```

This is my detail container which is gving me blank page

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import productos from "../../utils/productsMock";
import CardDetail from "../CardDetail/CardDetail";

import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../../utils/firebaseConfig";

import "./CardDetailContainer.css";

const CardDetailContainer = () => {
    /* DEFINIR PARAMETROS EN RUTA PARA QUE FUNCIONE */
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

    const productFilter = productos.find((product) => {
        return product.id == id;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        getProduct()
        .then( (prod) => {
            console.log("Respuesta getProduct: ", prod)
            setProduct(prod)
        })
    }, [id]);

    
    const getProduct = async() => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "productos", id)
        const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef)
        let product = docSnapshot.data()
        product.id = docSnapshot.id
        return product
    }
    

    return (
            <div className="details-container">
                <CardDetail data={product} />
            </div>
    );
};

export default CardDetailContainer;
```

Screenshot of console:
[image]

I would really appreciate some help, if you need more info please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit you question and post the code as _text_ instead of images? Also are there any errors in the console? Initially you are passing an empty object to `CardDetail` component. Are you sure that is not causing any issues?

Comment: Thanks, changed the image to code and added the console error!

Comment: Can you try `console.log(id, docSnapshot.data().id)` after the `let product` line (and before setting `product.id`) and also share a screenshot of the document begin queried from Firestore console?

Comment: Tried the console.log but is returning nothing on console. And for the screenshot i think i didnt understood what you said. Here's the repo maybe that helps https://github.com/LucasETrigo/ecom-react-app . Thanks

Comment: Your ID is not logged if you try to  `console.log(id)` at start of `getProduct()` function either?